# What determines the "tag" shown in the site title when visiting a question?

Tags: support, tags

I recently created a question titled "Use external stylesheet from resource with Batik in Java" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437633/use-external-stylesheet-from-resource-with-batik-in-java)). It has the tags [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), [batik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batik). When looking at the title of the site it is:

```
<title>css - Use external stylesheet from resource with Batik in Java - Stack Overflow</title>
```

My opinion is that the CSS tag relevance is low, while the Java tag relevance is high. I specified the Java tag first (unclear if order matters). What determines which tag is included in the site title? Am I able to affect this decision?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also sheds some light in the "**Don't include tags in the title**" section.

Comment: @ThomA don't use tags as tags - that is, disporate piece of information tacked onto the title. The same word that is in a tag can just be part of a regular sentence, however.

Comment: @VLAZ those aren't my words, that's the words of the article; and it goes on to discuss why and how you should write a title (including use of "in regular English" when a tag is referenced). Am I missing something?

Comment: @ThomA just adding more information to what you mentioned.

Comment: I see. Most popular tag prepended. Thanks!